# What is the best Meteor package for User login with profile manipulation?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

am building a website where users can post their own items for sale. am looking for a way that i can add user profile for each user, in the profile i want to add the amount of users that bought his item and other related information.

is it possible to do it with accounts-ui and accounts-password packages?

or are there any other advisable packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manipulate the user profile by simply adding fields to the `profile` key, and updating the user in the Meteor.users collection

Comment: Be aware if using profile that this is editable from client by default even with insecure package removed so storing data you don't want a user to change here is a nono (like data about sales etc)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @PhilipPryde. You probably don't want to add the fields to profile. Read this: [guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#custom-user-data](http://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#custom-user-data). its a good explanation and recommends putting the fields at the top level of the user object in the users collection.